# bootstrap (3.3.7) youtube style image carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Without reinventing the wheel, I want to make something that is a bootstrap (or css, or jquery is fine) image slider similiar to what youtube looks like.

I.e., 4 'thumbnails' that you can click on arrows to slide right/left.

Can't seem to find any good free demos (or rather, ones that actually work), and don't want to reinvent the wheel. Can anyone recommend something that works?

This is what I want to accomplish:[image]
something like say (really condensing here):

```
 <div id=item1 img=1.jpg caption='picture 1'>
 <div id=item2 img=2.jpg caption='picture 2'>
 <div id=item3 img=3.jpg caption='picture 3'>
 <div id=item4 img=4.jpg caption='picture 4'>
 <div id=item5 img=5.jpg caption='picture 5'>
```

with the left right arrows

doesn't "have" to be bootstrap (btw I am using version 3.3.7 and can't change that), could be pure CSS, or jquery...

any recommendations would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://codepen.io/ryanfitton/pen/paggdY?editors=1010)? You'll need to replace `<iframe>` with images though

Comment: hi - i am looking for something specifically where I can set the number of thumbnail images just like the youtube image example. i.e., say I have "10" images, I want to have "4" images that show on the screen at any time, and using arrow keys will 'move' the set of slides left/right, bringing the other slides into view

Comment: that example only has '1' image at any time and slides back & forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for multi-item carousel with one item slide each move?

Probably want to check this code snippet out: https://www.bootply.com/JrJtm5y9Pt.

However, you may want to rewrite and deleted some of codes (unnecessary style, html, etc).
I eventually end-up using the idea and reinvent the wheel for my project (since many js solutions are based on jquery and occasionally some bugs are from lib itself, try to rewrite codes less rely on jquery).

Comment: YES! thank-you! this looks like exactly what I need, let me quickly test it out - if it works 100% I'll accept this answer, thanks very much! :)

Comment: okay, testing it... its 'almost' works. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7, and jquery 3.2.1, so I am not sure if this is affecting things... but instead of advancing properly, i.e., "[1] [2] [3] [4]" -> "[2] [3] [4] [5]", (i.e., just dropping the [1] and moving everything by 1 unit to the left, and adding a [5]" - it instead moves '4' units left (i.e., moves the entire block >>[1] [2] [3] [4]<< ALL the way to the left (so the 4 disppears), and the new block [2] [3] [4] [5] slides in from the right to left)any ideas how to fix? thanks!

Comment: @user6262902  Unfortunately , I believe the reason might be something to do with bootstrap 3.3.7 css ( you can try out the older or newer bootstrap css like 3.2 to see if it's true, maybe something else). They change certain behaviors but I cannot offer any valuable suggestions since I never work on bootstrap below 4.  If the issue is from css and you cannot change your bs version at all most likely you have to figure out a way to overwrite certain  BS css part.

Comment: kk, thx - i'll accept this because you helped set me on the right track (I found a version 3.3.2 that seems to work 'pretty' well), thanks!